# How to convert a list of interfaces to their respective derived classes? C#

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm using a 3rd party library from a company called oh let's say Mobi. They offer domain objects and a client that accepts THEIR domain objects, internally serializes it, and posts it to a rest endpoint.

I wanted to architect my code so that I'm not completely dependent upon them in case I want to switch out their library for something custom built or another 3rd party library. So I created identically named classes and inherited them from the corresponding 3rd party class.

for example:

```
public class Patient : Mobi.Model.Patient, IResource
{

}
```

I created IResource so I could have factory methods and polymorphism and all that jazz. So here's my issue, I can't use their client to post MY domain objects. I need to convert my domain object to their domain object to use their client.

For example:

```
var client = new Mobi.MobiClient();
IList<IResource> resources = new List<IResource>();
resources.Add(new Patient()) // my Patient class not theirs
resources.Add(new Doctor())  // my Doctor class not theirs

foreach(var resource in resources)
{
    var mobiResource = MethodToConvertIResourceToTheDerivedResourceAndMapItToTheirResource(resource)
    client.Post(mobiResource)
}
```

So how would I implement the method to convert a base class to a derived class and then map it to an identical class?

I could have a bunch of "is" statements and then use something like AutoMapper but I was wondering if there was something that was more dynamic or easier. Also wanted to know if this is a bad way to do things.

Comment: I would recommend to not have your domain class inherit from the external class. I would recommend a wrapper class instead. So in your Patient class have a private field of Mobi.Model.Patient and then have a constructor that takes in a Mobi.Model.Patient and stores to the field. That way you can pass this around and if you need data from the external Patient, your wrapper class can take the data out of it, or simply 'unwrap' and provide the external Patient instance via `GetMobiPatient()` or something like that.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: A good way to do this is to have DTO's or mapping objects in your class and use the above mentioned automapper library to handle the data transformation to invoke their library.
Once you have your own DTO's or mapping objects, you can put them in a separate library so that in case you switch over to another 3rd party library, you can do it with ease.

Comment: @Saravanan I'm sorry I'm not too sure I understood . I think the automapper has to know the destination type of the object I want to map but I only have references to the base type.

Comment: For example: if you have `Patient` from your 3rd party library, you can create like a `PatientDTO` in your application. 
At the time when you want to invoke the methods in the 3rd party library, you will get the Patient from the PatientDTO (via Automapper) and then make the call. This is a little tedious but you can easily isolate the 3rd party library from your core application.
HTH

Comment: @Saravanan ok that makes sense. My only issue is that I have a list of different DTOs and they all inherit from let’s say IDto. Would I have to cast them to their subclass / derived type so that automapper knows which object to parse to?

Comment: No, you just have to say that the property (patient name) in `Patient:IDTO` is mapped to `Patient` entity's property `Name`. Rest of them are all taken care. If you have similar property names, automapper takes care of the transformation by itself.

Comment: @Saravanan ok thanks for the responses. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it. My issue is that each entity is wildly different so IDto wouldn't really have any properties and the derived class would have all the properties. I don't know what type parameter to pass to Mapper.Map<??> if all I have is an IList<IDto> and it contains completely different objects but they are pretty much identical to the 3rd party objects.